# Batch file will only execute first command (cmd + python, have read other answers here)

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, command-line

I would like the file to open command prompt and execute two simple commands, however the file only runs the first command - changing the directory. Manually I would type the cd command and then on the new line that appears, type the python command.

```
start cmd /k cd "C:\Users\PS\Documents\django_project"
& echo run cmd /k python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I've tried all combinations of &, &&, CALL, echo, run cmd, cmd

Comment: I'm not sure why you are running a batch file, (in cmd.exe) and from it opening two more cmd.exe instances! Does ```Start "test" /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\django_project" "P:\athTo\python.exe" manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000``` not achieve what you wanted?

Comment: That may just be my mistake however the python command does not work, I believe because I have multiple versions installed.

Comment: The ```P:\athTo\``` part of my advice is specifically to prevent such things from causing you an issue. You use the path to the version of python you need!

Answer (score 1):

This is a CMD issue. Enclose everything after the /k in quotes:

```
start cmd /k "cd C:\Users\PS\Documents\django_project & echo run cmd /k python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

It might get tricky if further quotes are needed 'inside' of the outside quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately the command line now shows a text string print of 'run cmd /k python manage.py runserver', followed by a new line showing the new directory (due to the successfully executed cd command). I've also tried with quotes inside.

Comment: Well, that is what the line says "echo...".  If you need the the python script to run in the said directory, then remove "echo run cmd /k "